# CI/CD - How to build only once

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I found good advice [here](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/8-cicd-best-practices-your-devops-journey):

*Eliminate any practices where source code is built multiple times. Even if the software has to be built, packaged, or bundled, you should execute that step only once and promote your binaries. Most successful CI implementations include the build process as the first step in the CI/CD cycle to package the software in a clean environment. This eliminates oversights and reduces the chance for errors to be introduced and/or missed anytime later. Further, the resulting artifact should be versioned and uploaded to Git each time so that whenever it is pulled the build does not change.*

I have three branches (develop, test, prod), but in the test and prod, I want to use an image that was built in the develop branch.

How to do it?

Here is my yaml.

```
build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - /kaniko/executor --context . --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination ${CONTAINER_BRANCH_BUILD_IMAGE} --target=build
    - /kaniko/executor --context . --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination ${CONTAINER_BRANCH_TEST_IMAGE} --target=test
```

Comment: Git itself has no opinion on how to build software or do CI. CI systems that are bundled along with fancied-up Git systems, as found on places like GitLab, do, but that's a GitLab (or other site) thing, not a Git thing.

Comment: Is that advice snippet related to your question?

Comment: @torek - I know it - thank You, I use GitLab to store images in a container registry.

Comment: @bartekch: I commented because I snipped the [tag:git] tag.

Answer (score 0):

> I have three branches (develop, test, prod), but in the test and prod, I want to use an image that was built in the develop branch.
>
> How to do it?

You need a place that exists between develop branch and other branches to hold the result. For docker images use a registry, be it your custom file repository, your custom docker registry, docker.io or GitLab container registry.

- in develop branch

  - build image
  - upload it to GitLab container registry
- in other branch

  - pull the image from GitLab container registry
  - use it